# Reemplazar linea y agregarle ; con replaceLine

Tags: bash, script

-Quiero reemplazar una linea de un txt por otra con varios ";", pero replaceLine me esta poniendo espacios en vez de los ;

Codigo Actual

```
replaceLine="sed -i '${LINE_NUMBER}s/.*/${date}";"${command}";"${date}/' agenda.txt"
```

El codigo actual hace todo como corresponde pero a los ";" los agrega simplemente como espacios en blanco dentro del txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cual es la idea de hacer

```
replaceLine="  ?
```

Deberías eliminar las " antes y después de ;

Prueba con:

```
sed -i '${LINE_NUMBER}s/.*/${date};${command};${date}/' agenda.txt
```